# Посчитать сумму значений по разным полям

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть List объектов PaymentEntity.

```
    public class PaymentEntity {
        private BigDecimal number;
        private BigDecimal fullDebtRemnant;
        private BigDecimal percentAmount;
    }
```

Необходимо посчитать сумму number, fullDebtRemnant, percentAmount. Каждую сумму считаю отдельно.

```
        BigDecimal sumFullDebt = paymentEntityList
                .stream()
                .map(PaymentEntity::getFullDebtRemnant)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

        BigDecimal sumPercentAmount = paymentEntityList
                .stream()
                .map(PaymentEntity::getPercentAmount)
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Как можно посчитать сумму каждого параметра в одно стриме?

Comment: проценты в BigDecimal)) это ж сколько процентов нужно))

Comment: берешь обычный for и считаешь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. При необходимости реализовать конструктор(ы) в `PaymentEntity` для инициализации нулями:

```java
class PaymentEntity {
    // ...
    public PaymentEntity() {
        this(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO);
    }
    
    public PaymentEntity(BigDecimal n, BigDecimal f, BigDecimal p) {
        number = n;
        fullDebtRemnant = f;
        percentAmount = p;
    }
}
```

2. Определить метод для суммирования всех полей в `PaymentEntity`:

- как статический:

```java
public class Accumulator {
    public static PaymentEntity add(PaymentEntity acc, PaymentEntity add) {
        acc.setNumber(acc.getNumber().add(add.getNumber()));
        acc.setFullDebtRemnant(acc.getFullDebtRemnant().add(add.getFullDebtRemnant()));
        acc.setPercentAmount(acc.getPercentAmount().add(add.getPercentAmount()));
        
        return acc;
    }
}
```

Тогда список можно просуммировать так:

```java
PaymentEntity total = list.stream()
    .reduce(new PaymentEntity(), Accumulator::add);
```

- метод класса `PaymentEntity` аналогичным образом:

```java
// class PaymentEntity
PaymentEntity accumulate(PaymentEntity that) {
    this.setNumber(this.getNumber().add(that.getNumber()));
    this.setFullDebtRemnant(this.getFullDebtRemnant().add(that.getFullDebtRemnant()));
    this.setPercentAmount(this.getPercentAmount().add(that.getPercentAmount()));
    
    return this;
}
```

Сумма рассчитывается так:

```java
PaymentEntity total = list.stream()
    .reduce(new PaymentEntity(), PaymentEntity::accumulate);
```

---

Тест:

```
List<PaymentEntity> list = Arrays.asList(
    new PaymentEntity(new BigDecimal("120"), new BigDecimal("1250"), new BigDecimal("10.5")),
    new PaymentEntity(new BigDecimal("150"), new BigDecimal("1000"), new BigDecimal("8.5")),
    new PaymentEntity(new BigDecimal("100"), new BigDecimal("750"), new BigDecimal("6.0"))
);

PaymentEntity total = list.stream()
    .reduce(new PaymentEntity(), PaymentEntity::accumulate);
    
System.out.println(total);
```

Вывод:

```java
number: 370; debtRemnant: 3000; percentAmount: 25.0
```